# Running HTML5 code in android app without internet connectivity?

Tags: html, cross-platform

Is it possible to have HTML5 files stored inside the .apk file of an android app and run the files on the android app without requiring internet connectivity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. If your a native Android programmer look at the WebView. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html

If your not, you could look at things like http://cordova.apache.org/ and http://www.appcelerator.com/platform/titanium-sdk/ and others. But honestly I've never meet a dev who has a good thing to say about these for any kind of complex app.

Comment: The developer.android.com page says that it will require internet connection and permission to connect to internet.

Comment: What do the developers say?

Comment: you need internet and permissions only if you accessing pages on the web I.E. www.google.com, if your only going to be using files that are stored locally you dont need to include the permission